# How do you add a Role to EntityFramework Core?

Tags: asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

Ive started a new asp.net core web application using the "individual user accounts" template for authorization.  It seems that all the configuration of EF happens in Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

But I cant find any examples, or docs on how to add a one.

Comment: Its not clear what your are looking for. Maybe [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/release/samples/MusicStore.Spa/Models/SampleData.cs) can help you.

Comment: @tmg that is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I had achieved this in this way. I created a seed method in an extension class to the DBContext class and called this in the configure method of startup class.

```
 public static class CrmContextExtension
{
    public static async Task SeedDataForContext(this CrmContext context)
    {
        // if there is no role exist then create some default role 'administrator' 
        var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        if (context.Roles.Count() == 0)
        {
            var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store,null, null, null, null,null);
            var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "administrator" }; 
            IdentityResult result = await manager.CreateAsync(role); 
            logger.Info(result.Succeeded ? "Role 'administrator' has been successfully created" : 
                "Couldn't create role 'administrator' in the seed.");
        } 
    }
}

 public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, CrmContext context)
    { ...... 
      await context.SeedDataForContext();
      app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
     }
```

Try this out and let me know if you face any issue.